# Laravel and CTE's

Tags: laravel, mariadb, common-table-expression, laravel-6, mariadb-10.4

I'm trying to convert the following SQL query into Laravel code using taudenmeirs' laravel-cte package.

```sql
WITH `cte` AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY channel_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS row_number
      FROM `Videos`
)
SELECT `Channels`.*, `cte`.*
FROM `Channels`
LEFT JOIN `cte`
       ON `Channels`.`id` = `cte`.`channel_id`
WHERE `cte`.`row_number` = 1;
```

The problem is I keep getting the following response from the server:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1140  Mixing of GROUP columns
>   (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal  if there
>   is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: with cte as (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER
>   (PARTITION BY  channel_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS row_number from
>   Videos)  select Channels.* from Channels left join cte on
>   Channels.id =  cte.channel_id where cte.rn = 1) in file 
>   /Users/mark/Workspace/api.site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php
>   on line 665

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya absolutely. I thought I had. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got this answer from taudenmeirs over on github where I submitted this issue as a bug. It turns out that the error is caused by a bug in MariaDB: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17785

The `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode is enabled in Laravel by default. You can disable it by setting `'strict' => false` in your config/database.php file.

This actually does solve the issue. However it would be better if the fine folks over at Maria could solve the underlying bug.